# csv import sqlite3 without specifying column types

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I have a csv file with about 280 columns, which are possibly changing from time to time. Is there a way to import a csv file to sqlite3 and have it 'guess' the column types? 
I am using a python script to import this.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a simple CSV file - [the site has some tips about simple CSV files](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles).  The better question here would be to ask, what data do you have that both spans nearly 300 columns, and is variant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are able to use a 3rd-party library in this project I recommend [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Using pandas you could do this in two steps:

1. [Read CSV file into pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html)
2. [Write pandas DataFrame to SQLite](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.sql.write_frame.html)

For example:

```
import pandas, pandas.io.sql, sqlite3

# some sample csv data copied from: http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=635
csvfilepath = '/path/to/file.csv'

# `index_col` set to False ensures pandas doesn't use 1st col of data as index
df = pandas.io.parsers.read_csv(csvfilepath,index_col=False) 

# connect to in-memory database for testing; replace `:memory:` w/ file path
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
pandas.io.sql.write_frame(df, 'test_tbl', con)
con.execute('select * from test_tbl').fetchone()
con.close()
```

Query results:

```
(u'C00410118',
 u'P20002978',
 u'Bachmann, Michele',
 u'HARVEY, WILLIAM',
 u'MOBILE',
 u'AL',
 366010290,
 u'RETIRED',
 u'RETIRED',
 250,
 u'20-JUN-11',
 None,
 None,
 None,
 u'SA17A',
 736166,
 u'A1FDABC23D2D545A1B83',
 u'P2012')
```

And with an introspective query you can see that pandas has done the work of creating the table and even inferred the datatypes:

```
con.execute("select * from sqlite_master where type='table';").fetchone()[4]
```

Gives:

```
CREATE TABLE test_tbl (
  [cmte_id] TEXT,
  [cand_id] TEXT,
  [cand_nm] TEXT,
  [contbr_nm] TEXT,
  [contbr_city] TEXT,
  [contbr_st] TEXT,
  [contbr_zip] INTEGER,
  [contbr_employer] TEXT,
  [contbr_occupation] TEXT,
  [contb_receipt_amt] INTEGER,
  [contb_receipt_dt] TEXT,
  [receipt_desc] REAL,
  [memo_cd] REAL,
  [memo_text] REAL,
  [form_tp] TEXT,
  [file_num] INTEGER,
  [tran_id] TEXT,
  [election_tp] TEXT )
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot!
I have 5 csv files with 280-350 columns each. You just saved me a lot of time defining column types.

Comment: This works fine for most of my files but one is giving me this error: pandas.parser.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 19 fields in line 22217, saw 20 I pass the csv test in with this: df = pandas.read_csv(io.BytesIO(string_buffer),index_col=False)

Comment: I'd have to see that line to comment conclusively. I'm sure malformed CSV data can cause that sort of problem.

Comment: I tried this, and it works for most files, but sometimes I get AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'type'
not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

make headers of the columns in csv as  the same column names in sqlite3 table. Then directly read and check the type by using type() before inserting into DB.